# File not being created in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, file

I am trying to open a non existent file and write to it, however when I run the script, no file is being created.

Here is the line of code

```
File.open("valid_policies.txt", 'a+').write(policy_number.to_s + "\n")
```

Comment: What does return this call?

Comment: Is an error thrown? Does it run but nothing happens?

Comment: @jkeuhlen it runs but nothing happens

Comment: And you definitely have permissions to write to the directory you run your script from correct? I added an alternative way to do the writes, see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I need to check if I have permissions, right now the revised way that you posted is not working either.

Comment: Your code opens a file and writes (let's say) 384 bytes to it and returns 384. (Do you not see `=> 384` in IRB?) If you now open another terminal you will see the file has zero bytes. That's because you haven't closed it. Once you close the file, or leave the scope where you created and wrote to it (allowing Ruby to close the file), you will see that the file has `384` bytes. If you can't find the file, it will be in the directory that is the current directory of the terminal window from which you ran IRB. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont.) By chaining the two statements in your code you don't have the file handle (`f` in the following), which you need to explicitly close the file. Instead, do this: `f = File.open("valid_policies.txt", 'a+'); f.write(policy_number.to_s + "\n"); f.close`. Incidentally, you have not stated your question. Do you want an explanation for the behaviour you have experienced? Do you want know how to correct your code? Both? State your questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.write` try this instead:

```
File.open("valid_policies.txt", 'a+') {|f| f.write(policy_number.to_s + "\n") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using:

```
File.open("valid_policies.txt", 'a+').write(policy_number.to_s + "\n")
```

That's a non-block form of `open` which doesn't automatically close the file. That means the data is most likely not being written to the file but is sitting in the IO buffer waiting to be flushed/synced. You *could* add a `close` but that only propagates non-idiomatic code.

Instead you can use:

```
File.write("valid_policies.txt", policy_number.to_s + "\n")
```

`File.write` automatically creates then writes to the file then closes it. It will *overwrite* existing files though.

If you aren't sure whether the file exists and want to create it if it doesn't, or *append* to it, then you use `File.open` with the `a` mode instead of `a+`. From [the mode documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode):

> "a"  Write-only, each write call appends data at end of file.
>        Creates a new file for writing if file does not exist.

Using `a+` will work but it unnecessarily opens the file for reading also. Don't do that unless you're sure that's what you have to do.

If I needed to append I'd use:

```
File.open('valid_policies.txt', 'a') do |fa|
  fa.puts policy_number
end
```

That's idiomatic Ruby. `puts` will automatically "stringify" `policy_number` if it has a `to_s` method, which it should have since you're already calling it, and it'll also automatically add the trailing "\n" if it doesn't exist at the end of the string. Also, using the block form of `open` will automatically close the file when the block exists, which is smart house-keeping.